# Cant get has_many and underscore working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

i am stack for days with this, tried everything.

I am trying doing a simple has many associations, but it refuse to work:

what i need is that each orb get an orb_type associated with it.

i generate the scaffolds:

```
rails generate scaffold orb_type nome
rails generate scaffold orb nome:string descr:text orb_type_id:integer
```

Make the rake db:migrate,

change the models:

```
class Orb < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orb_types
  validates_associated :orb_types
  attr_accessible :descr, :nome, :orb_type_id
  validates :nome, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end

class OrbType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :nome
  validates :nome, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  belongs_to :orb
end
```

And then tryed to make it work:

```
$ rails c
1.9.3-p448 :001 > tipo = OrbType.new nome: "Planeta"
1.9.3-p448 :002 > tipo.save
1.9.3-p448 :003 > tipo = OrbType.find(1)
1.9.3-p448 :004 > planeta = Orb.new nome:"Testname", descr: "TestDescr"
1.9.3-p448 :005 > planeta.orb_type = tipo
```

and in the last line i get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<OrbType:0x00000003dc02a0>
```

Whats the deal? the underscore and rails "conventions" are giving me headaches.

I saw a lot of another similar topics, but none of theirs solutions worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your association is the wrong way round. (Your scaffolds are fine, just need to switch the `belongs_to` and `has_many` around.)

Change your models like so:

```
class Orb < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :orb_type
  validates_associated :orb_types
  attr_accessible :descr, :nome, :orb_type_id
  validates :nome, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end

class OrbType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orbs
  attr_accessible :nome
  validates :nome, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end
```

Now an orb can be given a type and a type can be given to many orbs.

Comment: You are the first guy who really helped me in months! many thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Having an `orb_type_id` in your `Orb` model is part of the problem. You're saying that `Orb` has many `OrbTypes` but the `orb_type_id` would essentially just allow one and the `OrbType` belongs to the `Orb` which means that the `OrbType` would need the `orb_id`.

Assuming a many to many relationship is the goal you most likely need an association model:

```
class Orb < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orb_types, :through => :orb_associations
  has_many :orb_accociations
  validates_associated :orb_types
  attr_accessible :descr, :nome, :orb_type_id
  validates :nome, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end

class OrbAccociations < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :orb
  belongs_to :orb_type
end

class OrbType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :nome
  validates :nome, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  has_many :orb_associations
  has_many :orbs, :through => :orb_associations
end
```

Comment: I put orb_type_id there because some another tutorial told me to do so. And i got that example working... but it didn't have any underscore and i cant reproduce that for my case, for a reason that i want to know :P

Comment: The underscore has no bearing on the issue though. I use them all the time without problem with my models. It looks like the issue is your model structure rather than the naming convention. What are you trying to accomplish and I can update my answer. From the looks of your question, it could go either way with the Orb having just one or many OrbTypes.

Comment: I just want to make each orb item to have one orb_type

Comment: This answer attempts a many to many relationship, which isn't what the question asked for.

Comment: @Matt, you are correct. However, before the question was edited, it was not clear which direction the question was wanting to go.

Comment: @kobaltz Ah, understood. I edited your answer a little so that I could un-vote.